# Limiting the number of radio buttons checked by a user after submit in Symfony2 form

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony2. I have created a form which has 3 sets of radio buttons and a submit button. To display the form, I have used a FormType. Now, I have to apply a condition that the user can only select only a maximum of any 2 sets of radio buttons(and a minimum of 0 sets of radio buttons) and not 3 sets of radio buttons. If the user selects 3 sets of radio buttons and clicks on submit then I want to throw an error message to the user saying that "You can select only 2".

This is the FormType "SubscriptionsType.php"

```
 <?php

 namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class SubscriptionsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
 $builder

->add('event1', 'choice', array('choices' => array('1' => 'Tourism', '2' => 'Food party',     '3'     => 'South korean food', '4' => 'Cooking', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('event2', 'choice', array('choices' => array('6' => 'Cricket', '7' => 'Football', '8' => 'Hockey', '9' => 'Baseball', '10' => 'Polo', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('event3', 'choice', array('choices' => array('11' => 'Game 1', '12' => 'Game 2', '13' => 'Game 3', '14' => 'Game 4', '15' => 'Game 5', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('register', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
 return 'subscriptions';
}
}
```

This is the controller "DefaultController"

```
 <?php

 namespace InstituteProjectEvents\StudentBundle\Controller;

 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use InstituteProjectEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\Subscriptions;
 use InstituteProjectEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type\SubscriptionsType;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 class DefaultController extends Controller {

public function eventsoneAction(Request $request) {

 $subscriptions = new Subscriptions();

//Get the logged in users id
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$userId = $user->getId();

//Check if events already selected by user
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('InstituteProjectEventsStudentBundle:Subscriptions');

$query = $repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $userId));

if(($query == NULL)) {

   $subscriptions->setEvent1(5); 
   $subscriptions->setEvent2(5);
   $subscriptions->setEvent3(5);

   $subscriptions->setStudents($userId);

   $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType(), $subscriptions);
   $form->handleRequest($request);

   }

  else {

       $subscriptions->setEvent1($query->getEvent1());
       $subscriptions->setEvent2($query->getEvent2());
       $subscriptions->setEvent3($query->getEvent3());

       $subscriptions->setStudents($userId);
       $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType(), $subscriptions);
       $form->handleRequest($request);
  }

if ($form->isValid()) {
//Save to the Database    

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($subscriptions);
$em->flush();

  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('InstituteProject_events_student_eventsregistered'));
}

 if($current_date > date_format($date,"Y/m/d h:i:s a")) {
   return $this->render('InstituteProjectEventsStudentBundle:Default:registrationsclosed.html.twig');
   }
 else {
      $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType(), $subscriptions);

      return $this->render('InstituteProjectEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsday1.html.twig', array('form' => $form ->createView()));
 }
 }

/**
 * This action displays the Confirmation page on success.
 */
public function eventsregisteredAction() {
return $this->render('InstituteProjectEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsregistered.html.twig');
}
}
```

What is the validation that needs to be written in "DefaultController.php" to apply the rule of only selection of maximum of 2 sets of radio buttons and a minimum of 0?

Comment: Should count(array_keys()) be used inside if ($form->isValid()) {     }? If yes then how do we access the radio buttons options array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about applying `Callback` constraint to whole form fields?

```
...

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            ...
            'constraints' => array(
                new Callback(
                    array('callback' => array($this, 'validateForm'))
                )
            )
        ));
}

public function validateForm($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if (CONDITION) {
        // build and add violation
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can check `Request` object..

Comment: Can you write me the code specific to my code and which part of the code?

Comment: @sachintendulkar One more hint, if you embed subform to your main form , `$request->request->get('FORM_NAME')['SUBFORM_FIELD_NAME']` will return array of selected options, by this way you can check them..

Comment: @xurshid29 oh nice i completely forgot about callbacks.  great solution.

Comment: Thank you xurshid29 and Derick F

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you want to do you need to set

```
'required' => false
```

to event1, event2, and event3 since required is set to true by default.  Then you'll need to add a javascript (or jquery) listener for the form submit and have that insert the error message if all three fields are selected.  However, you'll run into the problem of not being able to unselect a radio button since once you select a radio button you can't unselect it, so once you have selected something for all three you'll never be able to submit the form without refreshing the page. So you may want to do some workflow changes if you take this route.

Alternatively, you can just do a manual check in your controller and then add the error manually by

```
$form->get('event3')->addError('you can only select 2');
```

but you'll need to 'clear' your subscriptions otherwise it will re-render the form with the previous selections already filled and you'll enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you write me the code specific to my code and which part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, by replacing the following code in the above "DefaultController.php" :-

```
 if ($form->isValid()) {
    //Get the submitted form's data   
    $subscriptions2 = $form->getData();

    //To check if the user has selected more than 2 events or not

    if(($subscriptions2->getEvent1() != 5) && ($subscriptions2->getEvent2() != 5) && ($subscriptions2->getEvent3() != 5))  {
        echo 'You can select only a maximum of 2 events';
        echo '<br>';
        return $this->render('InstituteProjectEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsday1.html.twig', array('form' => $form ->createView()));
    }
```

Here, it is to be noted that I have given all the "None of the above" radio buttons as value 5 in "SubscriptionsType.php" and 5 as the event id to all the "None of the above" in the table of "Events" in the database.